# The belt in Munchkin Quest

Tags: munchkin-quest

Is the belt in Munchkin Quest the hand, or is it a pile of cards face up on the table? Which cards counts to your hand?

Answer (score 4):

From the [rules](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/munchkinquest/resources.html), p16:

> **Your Belt**
>
> If an Item is not worn and does not require Hands, then it is carried
>   “on your belt.” Typical belt items are one-shots, mostly Scrolls and
>   Potions. You may have any number of Items on your belt.

Comment: To be explicit: items in your belt are in play and on the table in front of you.